# Grafana. Как раскрасить одно значение в зависимости от другого

Tags: grafana

Я хочу вывести последнее время сбора метрики, и в зависимости от того, сколько времени прошло, цвет должен быть зеленый или красный.

Например, я могу в queryA вывести время из метрики, в queryB `timestamp`, третьим запросом выбрать `Expression` и написать `$B - $A` и получить разницу.

`Treshold` - не раскрашивает одну метрику в зависимости от другой. В `value maping` я так же не могу указать значение другого запроса (или не разобрался как).

Т.е. мне нужно вывести значение метрики, но подкрасить её в зависимости от вычисления или значения в другой метрике или в соседней колонке таблицы.

Comment: Если используется панель Table, пожалуй самое простое решение будет выводить и значение метрики и время с прошлого сбора, но подкрашивать только последнее: уже несколько мажорных версий не поддерживает выбор цвета колонки на основании значения из другой колонки.

Comment: В зависимости от источника данных может понадобиться или использовать Transformations чтобы объединить строки, или переписать запрос чтобы он сразу отдавал данные как надо.